# It's possible use BIOS services on x86_64 linux kernel?

Tags: linux, bios

I want to use interruption 10h service to display on console but I don't know if it possible, I been investigate on the official documentation but I can't found the answer

Comment: I am 99% sure that Linux does not allow you to access BIOS services like that.

Comment: This might be better asked on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3):

A big part of the problem is that the INT 10h BIOS services are (mostly) not in 64-bit code. They're not even in 32-bit code. *They are written in 16-bit code.* To successfully run that old code, you would have to switch the processor into an operating mode that is entirely different from what a modern operating systems use.

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H)

> Furthermore, on a modern x86 system, BIOS calls can only be performed in Real mode, or Virtual 8086 mode. v8086 is not an option in Long mode. This means that a modern operating system, which operates in Protected mode (32 bit), or Long mode (64 bit), would need to switch into real mode and back to call the BIOS - a hugely expensive operation.

Before switching the CPU operating mode (which is a high-privilege operation, definitely requiring root access) you would need to set up the system state to match the expectations of that old code. For example, the BIOS ROMs are normally unmapped from the address space as they are not needed; you would to have to map their content back into your program's address space in such a way that they would be usable.

And *returning* from 16-bit code to a regular 32-bit or 64-bit user-space Linux program would be another tricky operation.

And on a modern system, you are very likely to have at least two or more *CPU cores* - something that the BIOS services were not designed to cope with at all.

In short, you're looking at a very complex task.

What do you actually want to do with your display? This feels like a very serious case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/379923).

If you still want to do it for the technical challenge, more power to you. I'd strongly suggest studying [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/) and its source code first to get some idea of what you'll be dealing with.